# Relationships in Django

Tags: python, django, django-model

У меня есть 3 модели: `Student`, `IndividualWork` и `TeamWork`. Мне надо так сделать, чтобы модель `Student` содержала ключи к двум остальным моделям. Условия такие: студент может иметь много индивидуальный работ, в свою очередь индивидуальная работа приписана только к одному студенту. Что касается групповых работ - то студент может иметь много таких работ, а групповые работы - соответственно много студентов.

```
class Student(nodels.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    ind_work = models. OneToOneField(IndWork, on_delete='models.CASCADE')
    team_work = models.ManyToMany(TeamWork, blank=True)

class IndWork(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')

class TeamWork(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
```

Я не совсем уверен правильно ли я делаю в случае `ind_work` . Конечно можно приписывать ключ `Student` в модели `IndWork`, но мне именно важна такая структура как сейчас в `Student`.

Comment: я так понимаю и в том и другом поле у меня должно быть ManyToMany?

Answer (score 1):

как я понимаю, из вопроса следует

> Условия такие: студент может иметь много индивидуальный работ

то для поля ind_work скорее стоит использовать связь [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) но в модели IndWork, аналогично и в TeamWork
Если задача сохранить поля как они есть то да, ManyToMany